# Merging multiple PDFs to Single PDF using VBA

Tags: vba, ms-access, pdf, ms-access-2010

I am working on a requirement where I am merging 14 individual PDF to single PDF file. Also I want to add page number to each page after merge.

Anyone have any idea how to add page number in PDF file using VBA?

I am doing coding in MS-Access 2010 VBA and to generate PDF I am using  Adobe Acrobat Standard.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier if you create a managed assembly, since there are lots of libraries that allow you to work with pdf files, deploy that assembly and use it from within vba as an activeX.

Comment: Hint: Convert to `.PS`, then merge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Path = "F:\Target.pdf"
'Path = Wscript.Arguments.Item(0)

Set App = CreateObject("Acroexch.app") 
app.show
Set AVDoc = CreateObject("AcroExch.AVDoc") 
Set AForm = CreateObject("AFormAut.App") 'from AFormAPI


If AVDoc.Open(Path,"") Then 
  '//write JS-Code on a variable
  Ex = "  // Set Footer PageNo centered  "&vbLF _
  & "  var Box2Width = 50  "&vbLF _
  & "  for (var p = 0; p < this.numPages; p++)   "&vbLF _
  & "   {   "&vbLF _
  & "    var aRect = this.getPageBox(""Crop"",p);  "&vbLF _
  & "    var TotWidth = aRect[2] - aRect[0]  "&vbLF _
  & "     {  var bStart=((TotWidth/2)-(Box2Width/2)) " & vbLf _
  & "         var bEnd=((TotWidth/2)+(Box2Width/2)) + 5  "&vbLF _
  & "         var fp = this.addField(String(""xftPage""+p+1), ""text"", p, [bStart,45,bEnd,15]);   "&vbLF _
  & "         fp.value = ""Page: "" + String(p+1)+ ""/"" + this.numPages;  "&vbLF _
  & "         fp.textSize=9;  fp.readonly = true;  "&vbLF _
  & "         fp.alignment=""right"";  "&vbLF _
  & "     } "&vbLF _
  & "   }  "

'//Execute JS-Code
AForm.Fields.ExecuteThisJavaScript Ex

App.Exit

end if
```

Comment: This is a VB script which uses Java script to add page numbers